# RDD Remove elements by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 RDD's that are pulled in with the following code:

```scala
val fileA = sc.textFile("fileA.txt")
val fileB = sc.textFile("fileB.txt")
```

I then Map and Reduce it by key:

```scala
val countsB = fileB.flatMap(line => line.split("\n"))
  .map(word => (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_+_)

val countsA = fileA.flatMap(line => line.split("\n"))
  .map(word => (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_+_)
```

I now wan't to find and remove all keys in countB if the key exist in countA

I have tried something like:

```scala
countsB.keys.foreach(b => {
  if(countsB.collect().exists(_ == b)){
    countsB.collect().drop(countsB.collect().indexOf(b))
  }
})
```

but it doesn't seem like it removes them by the key.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but you might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527765/checking-if-an-rdd-element-is-in-another-using-the-map-function/35527983#35527983

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your suggested code:

1. You are `collect`ing the RDDs, which means they are not RDDs anymore, they are copied into the driver application's memory as plain Scala collections, so you lose Spark's parallelism and risk OutOfMemory errors in case your dataset is large
2. When calling `drop` on an immutable Scala collection (or an `RDD`), you don't change the original collection, you get a **new** collection with those records dropped, so you can't expect original collection to change
3. You cannot access an `RDD` within a function passed to any of the RDDs higher-order methods (e.g. `foreach` in this case) - any function passed to these method is serialized and sent to workers, and `RDD`s are (intentionally) not serializable - it makes no sense to fetch them into driver memory, serialize them, and send back to workers - the data is already distributed on the workers!

To solve all these - when you want to use one RDD's data to transform/filter another one, you usually want to use some type of **`join`**. In this case you can do:

```
// left join, and keep only records for which there was NO match in countsA:
countsB.leftOuterJoin(countsA).collect { case (key, (valueB, None)) => (key, valueB) }
```

NOTE that this `collect` that I'm using here isn't the `collect` you used - this one takes a `PartialFunction` as an argument, and behaves like a combination of `map` and `filter`, and most importantly: it doesn't copy all data into driver memory.

**EDIT**: as The Archetypal Paul commented - you have a much shorter and nicer option - `subtractByKey`:

```
countsB.subtractByKey(countsA)
```

Comment: This was a really great answer. Thanks.

Comment: "you usually want to use some type of join.". True generally, but surely here you want `subtractByKey`?